# How to extract the last 7 number values in an alphanumeric string

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to extract the last 7 number values (not characters) from a string in an excel cell.  The string contains a file name (which can be a mixture of letters,numbers and a dash) and then 7 numbers which need to be moved to another column.

e.g. `Johnson Set1- 0 0 1 14 9 54 0`

The number values vary from 0 up to 999 so it is not possible to just extract the last 7 characters.

Comment: Is the substring to be extracted always preceded by a dash (-)? Is this always the ONLY dash in the string?

Answer (score 1):

So, there are a few tricks you can use to get what you want. I'll do my best to explain them here and then give you a formula that uses these tricks to give you want you want.

The key is to find the space before the list of numbers start. If your example is general enough, this space will always be the 7th space from the right. The trouble is that 7th from the right may be any number space from the left because it sounds like there aren't rules about the file name having a set number of spaces. And the `SUBSTITUTE` function allows you to specify which instance (from the left) of a string to replace.

To get the 7th space from the right, we have to translate that into spaces from the left. To do this, we need to know the number of spaces in the entire string. Once we have that, it's just a matter of subtraction.

To find the total number of spaces in the string, there is a trick using the `SUBSTITUTE` and `LEN` functions. The idea is to replace all the spaces in the string with nothing and then compare the length of the output to the length of the original string. The difference is of course the number of spaces in the original string. So for a string in `A1`, the following will return the number of spaces:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

So, the number instance of space from the left you want will always have 6 more spaces to its left.

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-6
```

Now, the next problem is that only `SUBSTITUTE` allows you specify the instance number you want to change. `FIND`, which would be most convenient for extracting the numbers, does not have this feature. The trick then is to use `SUBSTITUTE` to generate a string that allows you to use `FIND` as you want to. If you replace the 7th space from the right with a string that does not occur anywhere else in the string, you have a unique substring to search for. So, for instance you can use the following to replace the desired space with "REPLACE!ME":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","REPLACE!ME",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-6)
```

Now, you just need to find the index of "REPLACE!ME" in the string and return everything to its right. This can be done with the `RIGHT`, `LEN`, and `FIND` functions. The final function is kind of repetitive, but it gets the job done.

```
 =RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","REPLACE!ME",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-6),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","REPLACE!ME",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-6))-FIND("REPLACE!ME",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","REPLACE!ME",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-6))-LEN("REPLACE!ME")+1)
```

Comment: I've used the formula you provided but nothing happens -am I missing something?

Comment: Did you update the cell reference from A1 to whatever cell holds your string? You'll need to change all instances of A1.

Comment: Hi Excellll,yes I have changed the cell reference but I'm still not getting anything. Any further suggestions??

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting anything"? What does it return?